# Spdlog - how to manually clear a file with basic_file_sink_mt

Tags: c++, spdlog

Spdlog appears to have a `trancute` upon construction of `basic_file_sink_mt`, but other then that there appears to be no method that can be called to clear the file. My current workaround is to reconstruct the `basic_file_sink_mt` object so that `trancute` is called but this is not ideal as I have to reset the level of it too. Is there any other way supported by the library to clear a file a logger is writing to that I have missed?

Thanks